# How can I remap a key combination to a different one?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a keyboard with a US layout and there is a special key that triggers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (key codes 37 and 52).

The problem is that I'm using it with a QWERTZ layout (selected during installaiton) and thus it triggers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> instead.

I would like to correct this in all programs (X11 & console) that use this key combination. It seems Xmodmap only supports mappings of key combinations to individual keysyms, and not to a different key combination. Is there anything I can do about it?

My system: Linux Mint 17 with MATE

Comment: Are you talking about X11, Linux console, BSD, Mac...?